# compute $\sum_{I\subseteq K }(-1)^{\mid K\setminus I\mid}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Let I and K be finite set. compute $\sum_{I\subseteq K  }(-1)^{\mid K\setminus I\mid}$

Here is I come up with,

$\sum_{I\subseteq K  }(-1)^{\mid K\setminus I\mid} =\sum_{i=0}^{k}{k \choose i}(-1)^{i} = 0$

and why I have this is because, we know I is subset of K, and I has the size 0, 1, 2, 3, ... to k, where k is the size of set K. For each size of I, we have ${k \choose i}$ ways to choose i elements

There is ${k \choose i}$ ways for each i, and we sum over i from $0$ to k such that we can calculate all $(-1)^{\mid K\setminus I\mid}$

Then by binomial theorem, we have $\sum_{i=0}^{k}{k \choose i}(-1)^{i} = 0$

Do you think this is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct if $k>0$. If $k=0$, you get

$$\sum_{i=0}^0\binom0i(-1)^i=\binom00(-1)^0=1\;.$$

Another way to look at it is to notice that as $I$ ranges over all subsets of $K$, so does $K\setminus I$, so you’re really just computing $\sum_{I\subseteq K}(-1)^{|I|}$. Call a subset of $K$ *even* if its cardinality is even, and *odd* if its cardinality is odd. Then each even subset of $K$ contributes a $+1$ term, and each odd subset of $K$ contributes a $-1$ term, so the sum is just the number of even subsets of $K$ minus the number of odd subsets of $K$. Every non-empty set has the same number of even and odd subsets, so for $K\ne\varnothing$ the sum is $0$. The empty set has one even subset — itself — and no odd subset, so for $K=\varnothing$ the sum is $1$.

The fact that exactly half of the subsets of a non-empty set are even can be proved by your argument, but it can also be proved by other arguments, so using it to prove your result need not be circular.

Comment: ahh make sense. Thank you

Comment: @Timothy: You’re welcome!